# Implement MATLAB's im2col 'sliding' in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, image-processing, numpy

Q: How to speed this up?

Below is my implementation of Matlab's [im2col](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) 'sliding' with the additional feature of returning every n'th column.  The function takes an image (or any 2 dim array) and slides from left to right, top to bottom, picking off every overlapping sub-image of a given size, and returning an array whose columns are the sub-images.

```
import numpy as np

def im2col_sliding(image, block_size, skip=1):

    rows, cols = image.shape
    horz_blocks = cols - block_size[1] + 1
    vert_blocks = rows - block_size[0] + 1

    output_vectors = np.zeros((block_size[0] * block_size[1], horz_blocks * vert_blocks))
    itr = 0
    for v_b in xrange(vert_blocks):
        for h_b in xrange(horz_blocks):
            output_vectors[:, itr] = image[v_b: v_b + block_size[0], h_b: h_b + block_size[1]].ravel()
            itr += 1

    return output_vectors[:, ::skip]
```

example:

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
print a
print im2col_sliding(a, (2, 2))  # return every overlapping 2x2 patch
print im2col_sliding(a, (2, 2), 4)  # return every 4th vector
```

returns:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]]
[[  0.   1.   2.   4.   5.   6.   8.   9.  10.]
 [  1.   2.   3.   5.   6.   7.   9.  10.  11.]
 [  4.   5.   6.   8.   9.  10.  12.  13.  14.]
 [  5.   6.   7.   9.  10.  11.  13.  14.  15.]]
[[  0.   5.  10.]
 [  1.   6.  11.]
 [  4.   9.  14.]
 [  5.  10.  15.]]
```

The performance isn't great, especially considering whether I call `im2col_sliding(big_matrix, (8, 8))` (62001 columns) or `im2col_sliding(big_matrix, (8, 8), 10)` (6201 columns; keeping only every 10th vector) it will take the same amount of time [where big_matrix is of size 256 x 256].

I'm looking for any ideas to speed this up.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896841/find-a-3x3-sliding-window-over-an-image) answer help you? Or are you specifically looking for speedup of **your** code?

Comment: @ljetibo I've looked at and played with the accepted answer in that post but not extended it to do what I want.  I am open to any solution.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We could use some [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) here to get all the indices of all those sliding windows in one go and thus with indexing achieve a `vectorized solution`. This is inspired by [`Efficient Implementation of im2col and col2im`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25449279/3293881).

Here's the implementation -

```
def im2col_sliding_broadcasting(A, BSZ, stepsize=1):
    # Parameters
    M,N = A.shape
    col_extent = N - BSZ[1] + 1
    row_extent = M - BSZ[0] + 1
    
    # Get Starting block indices
    start_idx = np.arange(BSZ[0])[:,None]*N + np.arange(BSZ[1])
    
    # Get offsetted indices across the height and width of input array
    offset_idx = np.arange(row_extent)[:,None]*N + np.arange(col_extent)
    
    # Get all actual indices & index into input array for final output
    return np.take (A,start_idx.ravel()[:,None] + offset_idx.ravel()[::stepsize])
```

**Approach #2**

Using newly gained knowledge of [`NumPy array strides`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) that lets us create such sliding windows, we would have another efficient solution -

```
def im2col_sliding_strided(A, BSZ, stepsize=1):
    # Parameters
    m,n = A.shape
    s0, s1 = A.strides    
    nrows = m-BSZ[0]+1
    ncols = n-BSZ[1]+1
    shp = BSZ[0],BSZ[1],nrows,ncols
    strd = s0,s1,s0,s1
    
    out_view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A, shape=shp, strides=strd)
    return out_view.reshape(BSZ[0]*BSZ[1],-1)[:,::stepsize]
```

**Approach #3**

The strided method listed in the previous approach has been incorporated into [`scikit-image` module](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) for a less messier, like so -

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows as viewW

def im2col_sliding_strided_v2(A, BSZ, stepsize=1):
    return viewW(A, (BSZ[0],BSZ[1])).reshape(-1,BSZ[0]*BSZ[1]).T[:,::stepsize]
```

Sample runs -

```
In [106]: a      # Input array
Out[106]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [107]: im2col_sliding_broadcasting(a, (2,3))
Out[107]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  5,  6,  7, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  6,  7,  8, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  7,  8,  9, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 5,  6,  7, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17],
       [ 6,  7,  8, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19]])

In [108]: im2col_sliding_broadcasting(a, (2,3), stepsize=2)
Out[108]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  6, 10, 12],
       [ 1,  3,  7, 11, 13],
       [ 2,  4,  8, 12, 14],
       [ 5,  7, 11, 15, 17],
       [ 6,  8, 12, 16, 18],
       [ 7,  9, 13, 17, 19]])
```

---

### Runtime test

```
In [183]: a = np.random.randint(0,255,(1024,1024))

In [184]: %timeit im2col_sliding(img, (8,8), skip=1)
     ...: %timeit im2col_sliding_broadcasting(img, (8,8), stepsize=1)
     ...: %timeit im2col_sliding_strided(img, (8,8), stepsize=1)
     ...: %timeit im2col_sliding_strided_v2(img, (8,8), stepsize=1)
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.29 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 226 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 84.5 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 111 ms per loop

In [185]: %timeit im2col_sliding(img, (8,8), skip=4)
     ...: %timeit im2col_sliding_broadcasting(img, (8,8), stepsize=4)
     ...: %timeit im2col_sliding_strided(img, (8,8), stepsize=4)
     ...: %timeit im2col_sliding_strided_v2(img, (8,8), stepsize=4)
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.31 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 104 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 84.4 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 109 ms per loop
```

Around **`16x`** speedup there with the strided method over the original loopy version!

Comment: I know I shouldn't (the rules), but this just blew my mind. It took a neat little pile of papers to figure out why this works, and there's so many neatly used numpy matrix operation properties in it. I'd buy you a beer\upvote twice.... if I could. Thanks, this just made my evening.

Comment: @ljetibo Thanks!! Your comment just made mine too! Well, I jumped from MATLAB to Numpy not properly how to use for-loops, call it boon or curse, but I am loving it, specially because it seems that looping in numpy is expensive. Also, recently, I stumbled upon this nifty tool `np.take` that I wasn't able to use on any SO problem before, but fit in nicely here. Well, appreciate the good words!:)

Comment: @Divakar Thanks, this is awesome.  It works, provides a significant speed up, and it's essentially three lines of code.  I've been looking at your solution for the past hour trying to understand **why** it works. I worked it out on my whiteboard and I've got it now, but I still think it's black magic. The force is strong in this one.

Comment: @Scott Don't you love those stuffs! ;) I know I do! Well, may the force keep strong with it!

Comment: @Divakar If you're bored I have another scipy/numpy code optimization question that has had little traffic for almost 2 weeks now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871460/efficiently-multiply-a-dense-matrix-by-a-sparse-vector

Comment: @Divakar is very popular on the MATLAB tags.  His answers are [PFM](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=PFM&defid=7233425).

Comment: @rayryeng Seriously where do you get those text lingo!? ;)

Comment: Can you provide your final implementation? I have tested it (A as 512 x 512 and Blocksize, B as 16 x 16) and I have encountered an expensive computing cost.

Comment: @osjerick Not sure what you mean by final implementation. This is the entire work. Also, what were your findings with those datasizes .i.e. some runtime numbers?

Comment: @Divakar Sorry! Sometimes the runtime number is about 12 seconds, but most of time it's about 300 ms. BTW, when I have tested A as 1000 x 1000 and Blocksize, B as 100 x 100, Python raises a Memory Error, but I suppose that this is caused by my hardware configuration.

Comment: @osjerick Ah yes, being a vectorized approach, it needs to have enough memory to store *everything* by its very nature.

Comment: How do I extend this to 3D matrices? Let's say I have a 1k*1k*3 image, this method seems to return just matrices of shape B.

Answer (score 9):

For sliding window over different image channels, we can use an updated version of the code provided by Divakar@[Implement MATLAB's im2col 'sliding' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109068/implement-matlabs-im2col-sliding-in-python/30110497#30110497), i.e.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,4,4)) # Sample input array
                    # Sample blocksize (rows x columns)
B = [2,2]
skip=[2,2]
# Parameters 
D,M,N = A.shape
col_extent = N - B[1] + 1
row_extent = M - B[0] + 1

# Get Starting block indices
start_idx = np.arange(B[0])[:,None]*N + np.arange(B[1])

# Generate Depth indeces
didx=M*N*np.arange(D)
start_idx=(didx[:,None]+start_idx.ravel()).reshape((-1,B[0],B[1]))

# Get offsetted indices across the height and width of input array
offset_idx = np.arange(row_extent)[:,None]*N + np.arange(col_extent)

# Get all actual indices & index into input array for final output
out = np.take (A,start_idx.ravel()[:,None] + offset_idx[::skip[0],::skip[1]].ravel())
```

**Testing** 
Sample Run

```
A=
[[[6 2 8 5]
[6 4 7 6]
[8 6 5 2]
[3 1 3 7]]

[[6 0 4 3]
[7 6 4 6]
[2 6 7 1]
[7 6 7 7]]]

out=
[6 8 8 5]
[2 5 6 2]
[6 7 3 3]
[4 6 1 7]
[6 4 2 7]
[0 3 6 1]
[7 4 7 7]
[6 6 6 7]
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this together, this may come in handy.  You may consider adding a `%timeit` section comparing it to awful looping.

Comment: Thanks for putting up a more generic version!

Answer (score 3):

For further improving the performance (e.g. on convolution) we can also use batch implementation based on the extended code, provided by M Elyia@[Implement Matlab's im2col 'sliding' in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31404264/7071375), i.e.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(3*1*4*4).reshape(3,1,4,4)+1 # 3 Sample input array with 1 channel
B = [2,2] # Sample blocksize (rows x columns)
skip = [2,2]

# Parameters 
batch, D,M,N = A.shape
col_extent = N - B[1] + 1
row_extent = M - B[0] + 1

# Get batch block indices
batch_idx = np.arange(batch)[:, None, None] * D * M * N

# Get Starting block indices
start_idx = np.arange(B[0])[None, :,None]*N + np.arange(B[1])

# Generate Depth indeces
didx=M*N*np.arange(D)
start_idx=(didx[None, :, None]+start_idx.ravel()).reshape((-1,B[0],B[1]))

# Get offsetted indices across the height and width of input array
offset_idx = np.arange(row_extent)[None, :, None]*N + np.arange(col_extent)

# Get all actual indices & index into input array for final output
act_idx = (batch_idx + 
    start_idx.ravel()[None, :, None] + 
    offset_idx[:,::skip[0],::skip[1]].ravel())

out = np.take (A, act_idx)
```

**Testing** sample run:

```
A = 
[[[[ 1  2  3  4]
   [ 5  6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11 12]
   [13 14 15 16]]]


 [[[17 18 19 20]
   [21 22 23 24]
   [25 26 27 28]
   [29 30 31 32]]]


 [[[33 34 35 36]
   [37 38 39 40]
   [41 42 43 44]
   [45 46 47 48]]]] 


out = 
[[[ 1  2  3  9 10 11]
  [ 2  3  4 10 11 12]
  [ 5  6  7 13 14 15]
  [ 6  7  8 14 15 16]]

 [[17 18 19 25 26 27]
  [18 19 20 26 27 28]
  [21 22 23 29 30 31]
  [22 23 24 30 31 32]]

 [[33 34 35 41 42 43]
  [34 35 36 42 43 44]
  [37 38 39 45 46 47]
  [38 39 40 46 47 48]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented fast solution using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) JIT compiler. It gives speedup ranging from `5.67x` to `3597x` depending on block size and skip size.

Speedup means how much times is faster numba algorithm compared to original algorithm, e.g. speedup of `20x` means that if original algorithm took `200ms` then fast numba algorithm took `10ms`.

My code needs installing following pip modules once through `python -m pip install numpy numba timerit matplotlib`.

Next is located code, then speedup plots, then console output of time measurements.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow30109068#main.py)

```
import numpy as np

# ----- Original Implementation -----

def im2col_sliding(image, block_size, skip = 1):
    rows, cols = image.shape
    horz_blocks = cols - block_size[1] + 1
    vert_blocks = rows - block_size[0] + 1
    
    if vert_blocks <= 0 or horz_blocks <= 0:
        return np.zeros((block_size[0] * block_size[1], 0), dtype = image.dtype)

    output_vectors = np.zeros((block_size[0] * block_size[1], horz_blocks * vert_blocks), dtype = image.dtype)
    itr = 0
    
    for v_b in range(vert_blocks):
        for h_b in range(horz_blocks):
            output_vectors[:, itr] = image[v_b: v_b + block_size[0], h_b: h_b + block_size[1]].ravel()
            itr += 1

    return output_vectors[:, ::skip]


# ----- Fast Numba Implementation -----
    
import numba

@numba.njit(cache = True)
def im2col_sliding_numba(image, block_size, skip = 1):
    assert skip >= 1
    rows, cols = image.shape
    horz_blocks = cols - block_size[1] + 1
    vert_blocks = rows - block_size[0] + 1
    
    if vert_blocks <= 0 or horz_blocks <= 0:
        return np.zeros((block_size[0] * block_size[1], 0), dtype = image.dtype)
    
    res = np.zeros((block_size[0] * block_size[1], (horz_blocks * vert_blocks + skip - 1) // skip), dtype = image.dtype)
    itr, to_skip, v_b = 0, 0, 0
    
    while True:
        v_b += to_skip // horz_blocks
        if v_b >= vert_blocks:
            break
        h_b_start = to_skip % horz_blocks
        h_cnt = (horz_blocks - h_b_start + skip - 1) // skip
        for i, h_b in zip(range(itr, itr + h_cnt), range(h_b_start, horz_blocks, skip)):
            ii = 0
            for iv in range(v_b, v_b + block_size[0]):
                for ih in range(h_b, h_b + block_size[1]):
                    res[ii, i] = image[iv, ih]
                    ii += 1
        to_skip = skip - (horz_blocks - h_b_start - skip * (h_cnt - 1))
        itr += h_cnt
        v_b += 1
        
    assert itr == res.shape[1]#, (itr, res.shape)

    return res


# ----- Testing -----

from timerit import Timerit
Timerit._default_asciimode = True

side = 256
a = np.random.randint(0, 256, (side, side), dtype = np.uint8)

stats = []

for block_size in [16, 8, 4, 2, 1]:
    for skip_size in [1, 2, 5, 11, 23]:
        print(f'block_size {block_size} skip_size {skip_size}', flush = True)
        for ifn, f in enumerate([im2col_sliding, im2col_sliding_numba]):
            print(f'{f.__name__}: ', end = '', flush = True)
            tim = Timerit(num = 3, verbose = 1)
            for i, t in enumerate(tim):
                if i == 0 and ifn == 1:
                    f(a, (block_size, block_size), skip_size)
                with t:
                    r = f(a, (block_size, block_size), skip_size)
            rt = tim.mean()
            if ifn == 0:
                bt, ba = rt, r
            else:
                assert np.array_equal(ba, r)
                print(f'speedup {round(bt / rt, 2)}x')
                stats.append({
                    'block_size': block_size,
                    'skip_size': skip_size,
                    'speedup': bt / rt,
                })

stats = sorted(stats, key = lambda e: e['speedup'])

import math, matplotlib, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(len(stats))
y = np.array([e['speedup'] for e in stats])

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.8, 7.2)

for scale in ['linear', 'log']:
    plt.clf()
    plt.xlabel('iteration')
    plt.ylabel(f'speedup_{scale}')
    plt.yscale(scale)
    plt.scatter(x, y, marker = '.')
    for i in range(x.size):
        plt.annotate(
            (f"b{str(stats[i]['block_size']).zfill(2)}s{str(stats[i]['skip_size']).zfill(2)}\n" +
             f"x{round(stats[i]['speedup'], 2 if stats[i]['speedup'] < 100 else 1 if stats[i]['speedup'] < 1000 else None)}"),
            (x[i], y[i]), fontsize = 'small',
        )
    plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.055, right = 0.99, bottom = 0.08, top = 0.99)
    plt.xlim(left = -0.1)
    if scale == 'linear':
        ymin, ymax = np.amin(y), np.amax(y)
        plt.ylim((ymin - (ymax - ymin) * 0.02, ymax + (ymax - ymin) * 0.05))
        plt.yticks([ymin] + [e for e in plt.yticks()[0] if ymin + 0.01 < e < ymax - 0.01] + [ymax])
        #plt.gca().get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))
    plt.savefig(f'im2col_numba_{scale}.png', dpi = 150)
    plt.show()
```

Next plots have iteration as `x` axis, speedup as `y` axis, first plot has `linear` `y` axis, second plot has `logarithmic` `y` axis. Also each point has labels `bXXsYYxZZ` where `XX` equals to block size, `YY` equals to skip (step) size, `ZZ` equals to speedup.

Linear plot:

[image: linear plot]

Logarithmic plot:

[image: log plot]

Console output:

```
block_size 16 skip_size 1
im2col_sliding: Timed best=549.069 ms, mean=549.069 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=96.841 ms, mean=96.841 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 5.67x
block_size 16 skip_size 2
im2col_sliding: Timed best=559.396 ms, mean=559.396 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=71.132 ms, mean=71.132 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 7.86x
block_size 16 skip_size 5
im2col_sliding: Timed best=561.030 ms, mean=561.030 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=15.000 ms, mean=15.000 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 37.4x
block_size 16 skip_size 11
im2col_sliding: Timed best=559.045 ms, mean=559.045 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=6.719 ms, mean=6.719 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 83.21x
block_size 16 skip_size 23
im2col_sliding: Timed best=562.462 ms, mean=562.462 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=2.514 ms, mean=2.514 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 223.72x
block_size 8 skip_size 1
im2col_sliding: Timed best=373.790 ms, mean=373.790 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=17.441 ms, mean=17.441 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 21.43x
block_size 8 skip_size 2
im2col_sliding: Timed best=375.858 ms, mean=375.858 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=8.791 ms, mean=8.791 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 42.75x
block_size 8 skip_size 5
im2col_sliding: Timed best=376.767 ms, mean=376.767 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=3.115 ms, mean=3.115 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 120.94x
block_size 8 skip_size 11
im2col_sliding: Timed best=378.284 ms, mean=378.284 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=1.406 ms, mean=1.406 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 268.97x
block_size 8 skip_size 23
im2col_sliding: Timed best=376.268 ms, mean=376.268 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=661.404 us, mean=661.404 +- 0.0 us
speedup 568.89x
block_size 4 skip_size 1
im2col_sliding: Timed best=378.813 ms, mean=378.813 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=4.950 ms, mean=4.950 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 76.54x
block_size 4 skip_size 2
im2col_sliding: Timed best=377.620 ms, mean=377.620 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=2.119 ms, mean=2.119 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 178.24x
block_size 4 skip_size 5
im2col_sliding: Timed best=374.792 ms, mean=374.792 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=854.986 us, mean=854.986 +- 0.0 us
speedup 438.36x
block_size 4 skip_size 11
im2col_sliding: Timed best=373.296 ms, mean=373.296 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=415.028 us, mean=415.028 +- 0.0 us
speedup 899.45x
block_size 4 skip_size 23
im2col_sliding: Timed best=374.075 ms, mean=374.075 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=219.491 us, mean=219.491 +- 0.0 us
speedup 1704.28x
block_size 2 skip_size 1
im2col_sliding: Timed best=377.698 ms, mean=377.698 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=1.477 ms, mean=1.477 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 255.67x
block_size 2 skip_size 2
im2col_sliding: Timed best=378.155 ms, mean=378.155 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=841.298 us, mean=841.298 +- 0.0 us
speedup 449.49x
block_size 2 skip_size 5
im2col_sliding: Timed best=376.381 ms, mean=376.381 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=392.541 us, mean=392.541 +- 0.0 us
speedup 958.83x
block_size 2 skip_size 11
im2col_sliding: Timed best=374.720 ms, mean=374.720 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=193.093 us, mean=193.093 +- 0.0 us
speedup 1940.62x
block_size 2 skip_size 23
im2col_sliding: Timed best=378.092 ms, mean=378.092 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=105.101 us, mean=105.101 +- 0.0 us
speedup 3597.42x
block_size 1 skip_size 1
im2col_sliding: Timed best=203.410 ms, mean=203.410 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=686.335 us, mean=686.335 +- 0.0 us
speedup 296.37x
block_size 1 skip_size 2
im2col_sliding: Timed best=202.865 ms, mean=202.865 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=361.255 us, mean=361.255 +- 0.0 us
speedup 561.56x
block_size 1 skip_size 5
im2col_sliding: Timed best=200.929 ms, mean=200.929 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=164.740 us, mean=164.740 +- 0.0 us
speedup 1219.68x
block_size 1 skip_size 11
im2col_sliding: Timed best=202.163 ms, mean=202.163 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=96.791 us, mean=96.791 +- 0.0 us
speedup 2088.65x
block_size 1 skip_size 23
im2col_sliding: Timed best=202.492 ms, mean=202.492 +- 0.0 ms
im2col_sliding_numba: Timed best=64.527 us, mean=64.527 +- 0.0 us
speedup 3138.1x
```

Comment: I was not aware of numba.  Thank you, very cool solution.

Comment: @Scott Numba is a special python module that allows to convert any quite simple python function to C++ optimized code and compile it to machine code. If function has a lot of loops and interaction with numpy arrays all of these operations are converted to corresponding C++ operations. This way numba on average can optimize any python code to run it `50x`-`300x` times faster. No special knowledge is needed, you just add `@numba.njit` decorator to function and done!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do better. Clearly, you have to run a loop of size

`cols - block_size[1] * rows - block_size[0]`

But you're taking a 3, 3 patch in your example, not a 2, 2.

Comment: In my example the columns are of length 4 (2x2).  Do I have an error or mistype something?

Comment: No it's just confusing because you're calling your function on 2, 2 and it gives the sub 3, 3 matrices. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add further optimization to M Eliya's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109068/implement-matlabs-im2col-sliding-in-python/31404264#31404264) (although not that significant)

Instead of "applying" skip at the very end, you can apply it when generating offset arrays, so instead of:

```
# Get offsetted indices across the height and width of input array
offset_idx = np.arange(row_extent)[:,None]*N + np.arange(col_extent)

# Get all actual indices & index into input array for final output
out = np.take (A,start_idx.ravel()[:,None] + offset_idx[::skip[0],::skip[1]].ravel())
```

You would add skips by using step parameter of numpy's arange function:

```
# Get offsetted indices across the height and width of input array and add skips
offset_idx = np.arange(row_extent, step=skip[0])[:, None] * N + np.arange(col_extent, step=skip[1])
```

and afterwards just add the offset array without [::] indexing

```
# Get all actual indices & index into input array for final output

out = np.take(A, start_idx.ravel()[:, None] + offset_idx.ravel())
```

On small skip values it barely saves any time:

```
In[25]:
A = np.random.randint(0,9,(3, 1024, 1024))
B = [2, 2]
skip = [2, 2]

In[26]: %timeit im2col(A, B, skip)
10 loops, best of 3: 19.7 ms per loop

In[27]: %timeit im2col_optimized(A, B, skip)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.5 ms per loop
```

However with larger skip values it saves a bit more time:

```
In[28]: skip = [10, 10]
In[29]: %timeit im2col(A, B, skip)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.85 ms per loop

In[30]: %timeit im2col_optimized(A, B, skip)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 ms per loop
```

```
A = np.random.randint(0,9,(3, 2000, 2000))
B = [10, 10]
skip = [10, 10]

In[43]: %timeit im2col(A, B, skip)
10 loops, best of 3: 87.8 ms per loop

In[44]: %timeit im2col_optimized(A, B, skip)
10 loops, best of 3: 76.3 ms per loop
```