# Need to grab a 3x3 neighbourhood of an input cell from a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to define a function that will return the 3x3 neighbourhood of an input cell.  Right now I have:

```
def queen_neighbourhood(in_forest, in_row, in_col):

    neighbourhood = in_forest[in_row-1:in_row+1, in_col-1:in_col+1]

    return neighbourhood
```

(in_forest is the input array).

When I run this, it only seems to return a 2x2 matrix, instead of a 3x3.  Why is this? It seems to me that I am inputting a row and column reference, and then slicing out a square that starts one row behind the input row, and ends one row ahead of it, and then the same for columns.

So for example, given an input array as such:

```
[ 01, 02, 03, 04, 05
  06, 07, 08, 09, 10
  11, 12, 13, 14, 15
  16, 17, 18, 19, 20
  21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ]
```

And then using row 2, col 3, I want to return a matrix as such:

```
[ 02, 03, 04
  07, 08, 09
  12, 13, 14 ]
```

Comment: Seems related to [`Implement Matlab's im2col 'sliding' in python`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109068/implement-matlabs-im2col-sliding-in-python).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say `in_forest[in_row-1:in_row+1, in_col-1:in_col+2]` you are saying "give me a square from `in_row-1` inclusive to `in_row+1` *exclusive*, and from `in_col-1` inclusive to `in_col+2` *exclusive*. It slices up to, but *not* including the second index.

Simply use `in_row-1:in_row+2` and `in_col-1:in_col+2` instead to slice including the "+1"s.