# python pyautogui module does not work when laptob monitor display is off

Tags: display, pyautogui

unfortunately pyautogui does not work when my monitor display is off. I want it to work correctly when I turn my monitor off. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Pyautogui looks the screen from a user's perspective. So anything you cant see as a user, won't be seen by pyautogui too. And by the time you switch on your monitor back it would have moved to FAILSAFE mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I worked it around using [vncdotool](https://pypi.org/project/vncdotool/). the remote machine I want to work with has x11vnc server running. I use vncdotool as a client to connect to it. you can capture the screen. I used this to map all the screen buttons I needed using cv2 module. To find the button on the screen[Find location of image inside bigger image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473952/find-location-of-image-inside-bigger-image), crop it [how to crop image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python)  and compare both original button to the one finded, if the comparisson % is good enought (for me less that 2%), it is trustable.