# How to check if 2-D array is in another 2-D array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

consider the two dataframes `df1` and `df2`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((6, 6)), list('abcdef'), list('abcdef'), dtype=int)
df1.iloc[2:4, 2:4] = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

df1
```

[image]

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), list('CD'), list('CD'), dtype=int)

df2
```

[image]

It's clear that `df2` is in `df1`.  How do I test for this in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the dataframes contain `0's` and `1s` only, you can use [`2D convolution`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) and look if any element in the convoluted output is equal to the number of elements in `df2`  -

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

out = (convolve2d(df1,df2)==df2.size).any()
```

---

For a generic case, let me use [`skimage` module](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.html) and [`this smart solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32531759/3293881) -

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows as viewW

out = ((viewW(df1.values, df2.shape) == df2.values).all(axis=(2,3))).any()
```

This is basically a template-matching problem and it has been discussed and we have gotten really efficient solutions under this post : [`How can I check if one two-dimensional NumPy array contains a specific pattern of values inside it?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531377/how-can-i-check-if-one-two-dimensional-numpy-array-contains-a-specific-pattern-o). That post also gives us the indices of all places in `df1` where `df2` could be located.

Comment: I just edited my question to not be zeros and ones.  It still seems to work.

Comment: @piRSquared Are you open to using external libs like skimage, cv2(opencv)?

Comment: @piRSquared And that `convolve2d` won't work with a generic case. To test out, you can change that `4` to -`4` in `df1` and check :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Brute force

```
def isin2d(small_df, large_df):
    di, dj = small_df.shape
    mi, mj = large_df.shape
    for i in range(mi - di + 1):
        for j in range(mj - dj + 1):
            if (small_df.values == large_df.values[i:i + di, j:j + dj]).all():
                return True

    return False

isin2d(df2, df1)

True
```

Comment: And Cythonizable too!