# Searching a smaller array in a larger array and returning the indices of larger array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, feature-selection, numpy-ndarray

I am working on Feature Selection. I got the selected features but instead of manually searching each time which features are selected, is there any built-in method in python that compare the first row (smaller array) of selected features to the first row of full features(larger array) and return the column numbers i.e indices of the larger array.

Comment: [`Like this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531377/how-can-i-check-if-one-two-dimensional-numpy-array-contains-a-specific-pattern-o)?