# Is there a method in numpy that verifies if an array is contained in another array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to verify if a numpy array is a continuous sequence in another array.

E.g.

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
b = np.array([3,4,5])
c = np.array([2,3,4,6])
```

The expected result would be:

```
is_sequence_of(b, a) # should return True
is_sequence_of(c, a) # should return False
```

I want to know if there is a numpy method that does this.

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840763/how-to-check-if-a-numpy-array-is-a-subarray-of-another-bigger-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We can use one with `np.searchsorted` -

```
def isin_seq(a,b):
    # Look for the presence of b in a, while keeping the sequence
    sidx = a.argsort()
    idx = np.searchsorted(a,b,sorter=sidx)
    idx[idx==len(a)] = 0
    ssidx = sidx[idx]
    return (np.diff(ssidx)==1).all() & (a[ssidx]==b).all()
```

Note that this assumes that the input arrays have no duplicates.

Sample runs -

```
In [42]: isin_seq(a,b) # search for the sequence b in a
Out[42]: True

In [43]: isin_seq(c,b) # search for the sequence b in c
Out[43]: False
```

**Approach #2**

Another with `skimage.util.view_as_windows` -

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

def isin_seq_v2(a,b):
    return (view_as_windows(a,len(b))==b).all(1).any()
```

**Approach #3**

This could also be considered as a template-matching problem and hence, for int numbers, we can use OpenCV's built-in function for `template-matching` : [`cv2.matchTemplate`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html#cv.MatchTemplate) (inspired by [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36535397/)), like so -

```
import cv2 
from cv2 import matchTemplate as cv2m

def isin_seq_v3(arr,seq):
    S = cv2m(arr.astype('uint8'),seq.astype('uint8'),cv2.TM_SQDIFF)
    return np.isclose(S,0).any()
```

**Approach #4**

Our methods could benefit with a `short-circuiting` based one. So, we will use one with `numba` for performance-efficiency, like so -

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def isin_seq_numba(a,b):
    m = len(a)
    n = len(b)
    for i in range(m-n+1):
        for j in range(n):
            if a[i+j]!=b[j]:
                break                
        if j==n-1:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: This tests something different from what the question is asking for.

Comment: The new versions don't work either. Among other problems, they ignore the order of `b`.

Comment: [Here's a demo of `isin_seq_v2` not working.](https://ideone.com/6pHBD2) I would show a demo for `isin_seq`, but Ideone doesn't have skimage.

Comment: [The new version of `isin_seq` doesn't handle duplicates.](https://ideone.com/b9569w) The new `isin_seq_v2` should work, though.

Comment: The note isn't quite correct, since problems occur [if the haystack array contains duplicates](https://ideone.com/T1Sulw), not just if the needle contains duplicates. (Also, I didn't realize you'd made the haystack the first argument instead of the second, so my previous examples have the arguments backward.)

Comment: @user2357112 Ah yeah, that's true. Edited.