# Find if 2D array is an exact subarray of another 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm stuck with the problem of testing whether or not a 2d array appears in the exact same order in another 2d array, e.g.:

```
01
23
```

in

```
000100
002300
000000
000000
```

would return *true*, but in

```
001000
002300
000000
000000
```

would return *false*.

I've already attempted to use scipy.signal.correlate2d but to no avail. Any help? Cheers!

)edit) Code for generating the data:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0,0,0,1,0,0],
             [0,0,2,3,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0]])

a = np.array([[0,0,1,0,0,0],
             [0,0,2,3,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0]])



b = np.array([[0,1],
             [2,3]])
```

Comment: can you add the array constructors to your question? and the exact command you tried

Comment: I've added the constructors. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

windows = view_as_windows(a, b.shape)

print((windows == b).all(axis=(2,3)).any())
```

would be the answer, as stated in
[How can I check if one two-dimensional NumPy array contains a specific pattern of values inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531377/how-can-i-check-if-one-two-dimensional-numpy-array-contains-a-specific-pattern-o)