# numpy sliding 2d window calculations

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, neighbours

I'm trying to learn a way to use numpy to efficiently solve problems that involve a sliding window in a variety of circumstances. Here is an example illustrating the type of problem I'm interested in:

I have a large 2d matrix, and I'd like to perform calculations on neighbors of every element in the matrix. For example, I may want to find the max value, excluding some special value of negibors at indexes at (x-1,y)(x+1,y+1) at each index, and put the result into another different 2d "solution" matrix.

Note that convolution2d, while useful won't work for me in this situation because I have specific operations to do at each pixel, and only want to do it on specific neighbors (of every pixel).

Also a bonus would be ensuring I don't go out of bounds.

Finally, is it possible to use any state as well? In cases where all neighbors are 0 I am hoping to assign a new integer id that I increment each time this occurs.

Here is an example:

```
Window:

0 0 1
1 0 0
0 0 0


Input:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 9 9 0 0 9 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Output:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Could you add sample input, output data for the edited part - `all neighbors are 0...`?

Comment: For the behavior described in the edit maybe [`scipy.ndimage.measurements.label`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) does what you want? Although it's not clear to me how this relates to the sliding windows.

Comment: @moarningsun This is a synthetic example to understand how to use numpy efficiently with a sliding window, rather than to solve the actual problem I'm describing.

Answer (score 3):

Use np.roll() to create secondary matrices. Then perform whatever operations you need between the initial and secondary matrices. For example, to take the average of the central cell and two neighbors:

```
sec_a = np.roll(mtrx, -1, axis=0)
sec_b = np.roll(mtrx, -1, axis=1)

result = (mtrx + sec_a + sec_b) / 3
```

Additionally, roll() rolls around the edges, so no need to worry about bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I once created this function to store sliding blocks from a 2D array into columns, so that any operation that we once thought to apply in a sliding window on a 2D array could be easily applied along the columns. Read more about it in [`this solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30110497/3293881) to [`Implement Matlab's im2col 'sliding' in python`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30109068/3293881).

Now, NumPy supports most of its functions to be applied along a specified axis. So, with this tool, effectively we would be able to apply almost any operation in a sliding window in a `vectorized` way. Here's the formal definition of it -

```
def im2col(A,BLKSZ):   

    # Parameters
    M,N = A.shape
    col_extent = N - BLKSZ[1] + 1
    row_extent = M - BLKSZ[0] + 1

    # Get Starting block indices
    start_idx = np.arange(BLKSZ[0])[:,None]*N + np.arange(BLKSZ[1])

    # Get offsetted indices across the height and width of input array
    offset_idx = np.arange(row_extent)[:,None]*N + np.arange(col_extent)

    # Get all actual indices & index into input array for final output
    return np.take (A,start_idx.ravel()[:,None] + offset_idx.ravel())
```

Here's how we can use this tool to solve the problem at hand, assuming `A` as the 2D input array  -

```
# Get 3x3 sliding blocks from A and set them as columns.
Acol = im2col(A,[3,3])

# Setup kernel mask
kernel = np.ones((3,3),dtype=bool)
kernel[2,1:] = 0

# Mask rows of Acol with kernel and perform any operation, let's say MAX
out = Acol[kernel.ravel()].max(0).reshape(A.shape[0]-2,A.shape[1]-2)
```

Sample run -

```
In [365]: A
Out[365]: 
array([[83, 84, 46,  9, 25],
       [32,  8, 31, 45, 58],
       [14,  8,  0, 51, 27],
       [31, 40,  7, 27, 71]])

In [366]: kernel = np.ones((3,3),dtype=bool)
     ...: kernel[2,1:] = 0
     ...: 

In [367]: im2col(A,[3,3])[kernel.ravel()].max(0).reshape(A.shape[0]-2,A.shape[1]-2)
Out[367]: 
array([[84, 84, 58],
       [32, 51, 58]])
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to essentially pass a lambda class where the .max(0) call is made? I forgot to include the state component of my question (which I've added).

Comment: @AndrewHundt Sorry, not really familiar with lamdas :)

Comment: well, any mechanism that handles the state component I added above, not particular to lambdas. :-) For example, any sort of class to be passed in and applied on each window, or some other technique I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your original 2D matrix is named A and has a size (n, m)

```
# extraction of 3x3 sub-matrices and storage in a new 2D matrix
B = [ [ A[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+2] for i in range(1, n-1) ] for j in range(1, m-1) ]
# conversion to a mask array
B = np.ma.array( B, mask=False )
# masking the unwanted elements of each sub-matrix
B.mask[:, :, 1, 2] = True
B.mask[:, :, 2, 2] = True
```

NB: the ranges of i and j at the creation of the sub-matrices have been chosen to avoid the boundaries.

Operations on a sub-matrix B[i, j] will ignore the masked elements.

Now, to perform an numpy operation (eg the max of the sub-matrix) on each sub-matrix and store the result in a 2D matrix  :

```
C = [ [ np.max(B[i,j]) for i in range(n-2) ] for j in range(m-2) ]
```

Comment: Cool that's interesting and covers the first couple steps, how do you perform the max excluding specific values and load it into a result matrix?

Comment: I suggest using list comprehensions, the same way the matrix 'B' was created. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following as a readable solution:

```
import numpy as np

def get_windows(arr, window_size=64, step=32):
  windows = []
  row = 0
  col = 0
  max_row, max_col = arr.shape
  while row < max_row:
    while col < max_col:
      windows.append(arr[row:row+window_size, col:col+window_size])
      col += step
    row += step
    col = 0
  return windows

a = np.random.rand(4, 4)
windows = get_windows(a, window_size=2, step=1)
```