# Implement MATLAB's col2im 'sliding' in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

[`col2im`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/col2im.html) and [`im2col`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) functions in matlab are important for image processing, however by googling there is no efficient implementation for python.

Especially I want to rewrite **col2im** for python using numpy

I have a matrix and I want to rearrange its columns into block.

The implemntations I found are not reliable by testing them it does not give the same result as matlab.

For im2col, the following implementation works fine

```
def im2col_sliding(A, size):  
    dy, dx = size  
    xsz = A.shape[1] - dx + 1
    ysz = A.shape[0] - dy + 1
    R = np.empty((xsz * ysz, dx * dy))

    for i in xrange(ysz):  
        for j in xrange(xsz):  
            R[i * xsz + j, :] = A[i:i + dy, j:j + dx].ravel()
    return R
```

But the related col2im is bogus !

Assume I a have matrix V of isze size(V) =  1 69169 
By running in matlab:

```
X = col2im(V, [3 3], [265 265], 'sliding');
```

It gives me size(X) is 263 263

But, In the python implementation related to the code I posted for im2col, returns an ndarray of **size (263 2) and not (263 263)** and the **values are incorrect** !

any help

Comment: Maybe you could start by specifying what exactly you want these functions to do? matlab function names are notoriously non-self-explanatory.

Comment: Im2col question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/30109068

Comment: @PaulPanzer 

I a have V matrix of isze
size(V) is 
1       69169
X = col2im(V, [3 3], [265 265], 'sliding');
It gives me size(X) is    263   263

In the python implementation related to the code I posted for im2col, returns an nd array of size (263 2) and not 263 263 and the values are incorrect

Comment: @hpaulj Im2col is fine for me and works fine, however for col2im is not the case

Comment: What col2im have you tried?  You don't give a source for the im2col; how are supposed guess the 'related' one?

Comment: @hpaulj from here https://github.com/fivejjs/nb_IBP/blob/master/eerwin_sliding_with_sigma_loop.py
im2col is fine (same result as matlab) whoever col2im does not return the same array shape and values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `im2col` `'sliding'`version, we already have few efficient implementations as posted [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30110497/3293881).

For `col2im` `'sliding'`version, it would just be a reshape away -

```
def col2im_sliding(B, block_size, image_size):
    m,n = block_size
    mm,nn = image_size
    return B.reshape(nn-n+1,mm-m+1).T 
      # Or simply B.reshape(nn-n+1,-1).T
      # Or B.reshape(mm-m+1,nn-n+1,order='F')
```

**Test runs**

MATLAB run -

```
>> arr = 1:15;
>> arr
arr =
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
>> col2im(arr, [3,3], [7,5],'sliding')
ans =                
     1     6    11  %// (7-3+1, 5-3+1) shaped array
     2     7    12
     3     8    13
     4     9    14
     5    10    15
```

NumPy/Python run -

```
In [116]: arr
Out[116]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])

In [117]: col2im_sliding(arr, [3,3], [7,5])
Out[117]: 
array([[ 1,  6, 11],  # (7-3+1, 5-3+1) shaped array
       [ 2,  7, 12],
       [ 3,  8, 13],
       [ 4,  9, 14],
       [ 5, 10, 15]])
```

Comment: @Divakar I need some Help for patch extracting in SPAMS lib(python). They have written code for extracting patches from Image but don't have any code for reconstruction Image from patches ?so, can u help me??

Comment: @SudipDas Please post a new question.

Comment: @Divakar I have posted, can u please check that question